# Avx2 intrinsics don't use all registers available. .NET 8

Tags: c#, compiler-optimization, simd, intrinsics, avx

I have optimised certain algorithms, using SIMD, such that they are latency-limited versus L1 cache.  For reasons known only to the C# compiler, said inexplicably emits code whereby it only uses ymm0 and ignores the other 15 ymmX registers.  Indeed, after every operation, it appears to store the result back to RAM (L1 cache) and then directly reload said from the very same location.

Given my current understanding, this is actual JIT output vs expected output.

When observing disassembly:

```
    mov         qword ptr [rbp-0B0h],rcx                                
Vector256<ulong> Accum_vec = Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector256(&zero);
    vpbroadcastq ymm0,mmword ptr [rbp-0B0h]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h],ymm0  

Vector256<ulong> A_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(A_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-60h]  
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-1B0h],ymm0 
    
Vector256<ulong> B_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(B_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-70h]  
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-0F0h],ymm0  
    
Vector256<ulong> C_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(C_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-80h]  
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-110h],ymm0  
    
Vector256<ulong> D_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(D_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-90h]  
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rcx]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-130h],ymm0  
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(A_vec, B_vec);
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-1B0h]  
    vpaddq      ymm0,ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-0F0h]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h],ymm0  
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(Accum_vec, C_vec);
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h]  
    vpaddq      ymm0,ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-110h]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h],ymm0  
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(Accum_vec, D_vec);
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h]  
    vpaddq      ymm0,ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-130h]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h],ymm0  
    
Avx2.Store(store_Ptr, Accum_vec);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-0A0h]  
    vmovups     ymm0,ymmword ptr [rbp-0D0h]  
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rcx],ymm0
```

Surely it should be:

```
    mov         qword ptr [rbp-0B0h],rcx  
Vector256<ulong> Accum_vec = Avx2.BroadcastScalarToVector256(&zero);
    vpbroadcastq ymm0,mmword ptr [rbp-0B0h]

Vector256<ulong> A_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(A_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-60h]  
    vmovups     ymm1,ymmword ptr [rcx]
    
Vector256<ulong> B_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(B_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-70h]  
    vmovups     ymm2,ymmword ptr [rcx]
    
Vector256<ulong> C_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(C_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-80h]  
    vmovups     ymm3,ymmword ptr [rcx]
    
Vector256<ulong> D_vec = Avx2.LoadVector256(D_Ptr);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-90h]  
    vmovups     ymm4,ymmword ptr [rcx] 
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(A_vec, B_vec);
    vpaddq      ymm0, ymm1, ymm2
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(Accum_vec, C_vec);
    vpaddq      ymm0, ymm0, ymm3
    
Accum_vec = Avx2.Add(Accum_vec, D_vec);
    vpaddq      ymm0, ymm0, ymm4
    
Avx2.Store(store_Ptr, Accum_vec);
    mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp-0A0h] 
    vmovups     ymmword ptr [rcx],ymm0
```

Is there are reason C# intrinsics only "understand" ymm0 (and 1 and 2 given other functions and their arguments)?

Why all the load/store, even if loading and storing the same variable?

Tried all manner of rearranging the SIMD code to attempt to get the JITter to output code using all sixteen AVX2 registers.  It didn't work.  JIT outputted code only concerned with ymm0.

Comment: did you build and run in release mode?

Comment: That looks like anti-optimized debug-mode asm.

Comment: Yes, the build is in release mode, in addition to turning off "detect debug methods" and further starting the EXE then attaching debugger after the fact.

Comment: Furthermore I should add that, while learning C# SIMD fundamentals and coding against an entirely different problem, I've seen the JITter output asm that utilises more than one register.  However there appears to be no rhyme or reason to it suddenly "giving up" and emitting code such as the above.  Given the problem I'm currently tackling exhibits a high-throughput _and_ low-latency requirement, each execution is causing somewhere in the region of 100,000,000 unnecessary read/writes to L1 cache.

Comment: IDK man, this very much looks like unoptimized asm, especially how it stores the result back to stack memory after every statement.  I've looked at C# asm from intrinsics on https://sharplab.io/ and it doesn't look like this, it looks a lot closer to what you'd get from a C++ compiler with optimization enabled.  (While the asm you posted looks exactly like what you'd get from a C++ compiler with optimization disabled, including using RBP as a frame pointer.)

Comment: Hence my frustration.  Short of dropping the whole problem to C++ or magic hand-crafted asm, I am at a loss as how to solve this and as to why the JITter refuses to utilise all registers.  The above example were coded to illustrate the problem - mine is significantly more complex.

Edit: And yes, it looks like completely non-optimised asm, yet this is all that I can coherce JIT to emit.

Comment: Additionally, Visual Studio appears unable to "see" any of the YMM registers.  Despite knowing that code is executing, however non-optimally, on YMMs they're perpetually greyed-out in the register view.

Comment: Didn't see your reply since you didn't @peter notify me.  Maybe take a look at what sharplab does to get final optimized code from the JIT; perhaps you're only looking at first-pass code-gen?  But even a first pass wouldn't explain the debug-mode style spill/reload, I don't think; it would be worth doing basic register allocation even for a first pass.  I don't use actually Windows or C# (I just know some about it from stack overflow), but I'd look for some kind of misconfiguration in your dev tools or project.  Or perhaps try on a fresh install on a different machine or VM?